# Sub query in dynamic query SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic, subquery

The following select statement is not working if it placed inside the dynamic query. It works fine if it moved out of dynamic query

```
DECLARE @sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , @AttributeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @sid = 'c0b5956b-47f2-4ad6-bb9a-67a5a249e4b7'
SET @AttributeID = 'F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM
        (select [CaseID],
            ( select 
                Attr.AttributeValue 
                from 
                [dbo].[CV_CaseAttributes] Attr
                Where Attr.CaseID = C.CaseID ANd Attr.AttributeID = @AttributeID
            ) AS CaseTitle
            ,[UserID]           
        FROM [dbo].[CaseMaster] C
        WHERE SpaceID =  @sid
        )
    AS Details'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@AttributeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER'
                  ,@sid=@sid,@AttributeID =@AttributeID
```

Error Message

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Why is this so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead (one `SELECT` is missing thus the error message):

```
'SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT [CaseID],
            ( select 
                Attr.AttributeValue 
                from 
                [dbo].[CV_CaseAttributes] Attr
                Where Attr.CaseID = C.CaseID ANd Attr.AttributeID = @AttributeID
            ) AS CaseTitle
            ,[UserID]           
        FROM [dbo].[CaseMaster] C
        WHERE SpaceID =  @sid
        )
    AS Details'
```

EDIT - as per comments:

try

```
DECLARE @sidV UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , @AttributeIDV UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @sidV = 'c0b5956b-47f2-4ad6-bb9a-67a5a249e4b7'
SET @AttributeIDV = 'F1A0D9D6-702E-4492-9EBC-63AD22E60E6A'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM
        (select [CaseID],
            ( select 
                Attr.AttributeValue 
                from 
                [dbo].[CV_CaseAttributes] Attr
                Where Attr.CaseID = C.CaseID ANd Attr.AttributeID = @AttributeID
            ) AS CaseTitle
            ,[UserID]           
        FROM [dbo].[CaseMaster] C
        WHERE SpaceID =  @sid
        )
    AS Details'

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@sid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@AttributeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER'
                  ,@sid=@sidV,@AttributeID =@AttributeIDV
```

EDIT - as per comments an "explanation":

I am no SQL Server expert so please take the following as a guess:

To me it seems that the parser sees things put behind `EXEC` as a new scope.
Thus when resolving variables by name it first checks within the scope of `EXEC` and upon not finding what it is looking for it expands the search to the surrounding scope.

In case of the original statement we had 2 variables named the same in both scopes (outside versus inside `EXEC`) - this lead to some problem when resolving those during executing the code inside `EXEC` and thus not using the declared variables from outside the `EXEC`.

By changing the names to be unique throughout both scopes the parser no longer had these issues...

Comment: The same error :(. The query works fine if i move it out of dynamic query.

Comment: @Yahia, I can see you've added 'V' to the variable names in the outside sp_executesql scope, but I can't see why this makes a difference and it's not clear what else you've done to solve the problem..

Comment: @TomHunter I am no SQL Server expert but check the EDIT with my "explanation" (more a description of what lead me to make these changed... a.k.a. as a guess)...